# How can I get stealthVersion from bitcoin's source code?

Tags: source-code, stealth-address

I found that a library called `Bitcoinkit` use stealthVersion.
**Network.swift**

```
public class Mainnet: Network {
...
    override var stealthVersion: UInt8 {
        return 0x2A
    }
...
```

I tried to search 0x2A,0x2a and 42(decimal from 0x2a) but find nothing in source code.

Is this calculated in bitcoin source code?

PS:
I found some Altcoin have a stealth.cpp which defined stealthversion:
(Verge)

```
const uint8_t stealth_version_byte = 0x28;
```

Comment: I suspect this is for a feature called stealth addresses, which are not supported by Bitcoin Core, so naturally you wouldn't find it in its source code.

Comment: I thought it too. But why it is 0x2A instead of something else?

Comment: You'll have to ask the person who picked that value.

Comment: Yeah. I have just noticed that. The value is same as the bitcoin's version. Mainnet is 0x2a, Testnet is 0x2b. I couldn't find these too.